# MySQL Stored Procedure not throwing error if it contains a query that succeeds

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, php, error-handling

I am writing a simple MySQL Stored Procedure, and calling it from PHP using PDO.

This is just simple enough to illustrate the problem I'm having.

This procedure `test_procedure_2`, does not throw any error.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `test_procedure_1`()
BEGIN    
    select 'gary';

    CALL raise_error;
END
```

It returns the result set:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [gary] => gary
            )

    )
```

However...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `test_procedure_2`()
BEGIN            
    CALL raise_error;

    select 'gary';
END
```

...this procedure `test_procedure_2`, when called, will actually throw an PDOException with the message `"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1305 PROCEDURE vjs_admin_dev.raise_error does not exist"`. And the `select 'gary'` query never gets executed. I like that.

Why is it that the first procedure did NOT throw an error when it clearly contained an error? I would like to come up with a stored procedure that, whenever there is an error anywhere in it, it will throw an error. Thanks for your help!

I'm using

- Ubuntu: 16.04, and
- PHP: 7.0.15
- mysql: Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.21, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

EDIT:
I have tried this with mysqli, and with PDO, and I get the same results. Here are some simple code examples that show my issue:

- Mysqli Version: https://pastebin.com/rATMST4H
- PDO version: https://pastebin.com/Wiq3yFmQ

The output of the Mysqli version is:

```
Running test_procedure_1
CREATE PROCEDURE `test_procedure_1`()BEGIN  select 'gary';  CALL raise_error;END
RESULTS:Array ( [gary] => gary ) 
----------
Running test_procedure_2
CREATE PROCEDURE `test_procedure_2`()BEGIN  CALL raise_error;   select 'gary';END
CALL failed: (1305) PROCEDURE vjs_admin_dev.raise_error does not exist
----------
```

The output of the PDO version is:

```
Running test_procedure_1
CREATE PROCEDURE `test_procedure_1`()BEGIN  select 'gary';  CALL raise_error;END
RESULTS:Array ( [gary] => gary [0] => gary ) 
----------
Running test_procedure_2
CREATE PROCEDURE `test_procedure_2`()BEGIN  CALL raise_error;   select 'gary';END
CALL failed: (42000) Array ( [0] => 42000 [1] => 1305 [2] => PROCEDURE vjs_admin_dev.raise_error does not exist ) 
----------
```

Comment: I think it ought to be returning two result sets - the first would be the 'gary' rs, and a second one with the error. Have you tried using mysqli, just to see if you get a different result? Also, how are you calling this from PHP /PDO?

Comment: @dbdemon I have added some examples of both mysqli and PDO methods of calling those procedures from PHP, as well as the output I get from those examples. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You seem to have swithed the order of selecting 'gary' and calling raise_error, but to me it looks like the mysqli output looks correct? Whereas the pdo output is still wrong.

Comment: @dbdemon In both examples (mysqli and PDO), I am calling both procedures. One selects and then raises error, the other raises error and then selects. In both situations, both mysqli and pdo are NOT showing me the error in the test_procedure_1. I did notice an issue with my example code, where I'm not calling next_result() to get more result sets, but even after I modify it, I'm still getting no error when I would expect one.

Comment: You don't seem to be _calling_ the procedures, but only _creating_ them.

Comment: @mustaccio, I am calling the procedures. What you are seeing is just what I'm echoing out, to make is clear what the procedure being called contains. Look at the pastebin links.

Comment: I tried this using MySQLi `multi_query()` and `real_query()` too, but I coulnd't get an error message after a valid result.
I tried exceptions with `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT)` and checking `mysqli::$error` and `mysql::$sqlstate`, without success.
However, if I run the procedure from _phpmyadmin_, it can handle the error! So, I will check the source code if I have time.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, that's a relevant problem, because **you can't identify an error in a procedure**, an this passes hidden next to some valid result! I think your question should be more popular.

After many tries and tests I found a way to solve it. You'd expect to loop through the procedure result set, until no more results are available (the [PHP Manual way](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.multi-query.php)). However, I found an alternate control flow to catch the errors after previous valid results:

```
<?php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
try {
    $sql="CALL procedureWithErrors()";      
    $conn=new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db);

    /*The usual way (does not work)*/
    $conn->multi_query($sql);
    do{
        $result=$conn->store_result();      
        if($result){
            while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
                print_r($row);
            }
            $result->free();
        }                           
    }while($conn->more_results() && $conn->next_result());

    /*This way works*/
    $conn->multi_query($sql);
    while(($result=$conn->store_result())!==FALSE){
        if($result){
            while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
                print_r($row);
            }
            $result->free();
        }                           
        $conn->next_result();
    }

    /*Just closing and error handling, not relevant code from here*/
    $conn->close();         

}catch(mysqli_sql_exception | Exception $e){    
    $error="Error #".$e->getCode()." ".$e->getMessage().PHP_EOL;    
    if(isset($conn) && get_class($e)=="mysqli_sql_exception")
        $error.="SQLSTATE #".$conn->sqlstate." Statement: $sql".PHP_EOL;
    $error.=$e->getTraceAsString();
    echo(nl2br($error));    
}finally{
    if(isset($result) && $result instanceof mysql_result) $result->free();          
    if(isset($conn) && is_resource($conn) && get_resource_type($conn)==='mysql link') $conn->close();
}
?>
```

The problems seems to be that `mysqli::more_results` and `mysql::next_result` return FALSE if an error happens, so they can't distinguish between an error and the lack of further results.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. You can not prevent execution of statements based on if later statements will throw an error in a stored procedure.

The only way to achieve something similar would be something like this:

```
drop procedure if exists test_procedure_3;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `test_procedure_3`()
BEGIN
    if exists (select 1 from information_schema.routines where routine_name = 'raise_error' and routine_schema = database()) 
    then
    select 'gary';

    CALL raise_error;
    end if;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

call test_procedure_3;
```

So you just check, if the procedure exists beforehand. There's no other way (I tried with transactions, signal, prepared statements and what not).

Comment: Hi there @tombom. I'm not trying to prevent the execution of the "select 'gary'" statement. I'm just saying that even in my procedure has the "select 'gary'" in it, if it later contains a statement that should throw an error.... the procedure should report that error in some way.